# Specify global context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, global-variables

In JavaScript, is it possible to specify the global context which will be used if a local variable isn't defined?

Example:

```
(function foo() {
    console.log(bar);
})();
```

It will actually print `window.bar`.

Can I somehow change the global context? Something like this:

```
var myGlobalContext = { bar: "foo" };

(function foo() {
    console.log(bar);
}).applyWithGlobal(myGlobalContext);
```

It should print `myGlobalContext.bar`.

Or attach `this` to be the global context?

I hope the example is clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is mask the global variables using a `with` statement.

```
var myGlobalContext = {bar: "foo"};

with(myGlobalContext)
{
    console.log(bar);
}
```

This is not the same as changing the global context, because other globals that aren't found in `myGlobalContext` will still exist.

In general, the `with` statement is [bad](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/), but it sounds like your use case might be one where it makes sense.

Comment: +1 Read all about it here: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-4-scope-chain/#scope-chain-of-the-global-and-eval-contexts

Comment: Also: "in general" is *not* the same as "Crockford said" :)

Comment: @David Well, in general, Crockford is insane, but that article explains the problem with `with` pretty well.

Comment: What would happen if `window.bar` was defined?

Comment: @MartinMajer It would check for the existence of bar in `myGlobalContext` just before `window`. `myGlobalContext.bar` if it exists, otherwise `window.bar`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and referencing the variable via `this.xyz` inside the function:

```
(function foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}).call(myGlobalContext);
```

The only other way is by wrapping the function call in another scope:

```
(function() {
    var bar = '123';

    (function() {
        console.log(bar);
    })();
})();
```

Comment: I know - but is it possible to access `bar` without using `this` keyword?

Comment: @MartinMajer I've added an example of that, too.

Comment: @MartinMajer Why? That's very confusing to anyone reading your code - an undeclared variable should always be considered to be global scope. If you want to use a different keyword other than `this`, you can use my answer and pass in the namespace into the IIFE.

Comment: The code will be autogenerated. I would like to compile `{=writeMe}` to something like this: `function template(context, writer) { writer(context.writeMe); }`

This works fine, but it also means some additional parsing, because I have to decide where to add `context.`. So it would be nice if I could just use `writeMe` instead of `context.writeMe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this by passing the namespace to the IIFE:

```
var myNamespace = { bar: "foo" };

(function( ns ) {
  console.log( ns.bar );
}( myNamespace ));
```