# How to change global context for new Function(...)?

Tags: javascript

I would like to specify the global context for a given function whilst leaving its local scope intact. After some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338445/specify-global-context-in-javascript) this turned out as close and somewhat working:

```
// that iframe is created via document.write to share objects 
var iFrameGlobal = myIFrameGlobal;

(function( ns ) {
  var context = this; // is the iframe's global, correct!
}( iFrameGlobal ));
```

Now as said, I would like to retain the scope of a function in that iframe context intact:

```
 var realGlobal = window;// the creator source of the iframe

 var iFrameGlobal = myIFrameGlobal;


(function( ns ) {


  // is the iframe's global, correct!
  var context = this; 

  // button is a custom HTML element in the iFrame, its owner document    
  // is correct. Its basically a custom widget, its JS has been parsed   
  // in that iframe as well.
  var myWidget = button;

  //the content of the new function 
  var script = "var context = window; console.dir(context); return context"; 

  var fn = new Function("{" + script + "}");

  var result = fn.apply(myWidget, _args || {});//returns realGlobal      


}( iFrameGlobal ));
```

So as you might see, changing global context did work, but the context did fall back to its parent document when the new function has been parsed.

Is that on purpose? I saw also this answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686476/functions-in-global-context) which mentions this behavior but it doesn't makes sense to me since 'this' is correct and functions below should traverse up to it.

ps:

- this was tested against Firefox-29 and Firebug 1.12(must run there)
- actually, i want run 'scripts' containing $('#otherButton').css(...) in that iframe, from within custom scope passed via fn.apply(myWidget,...);

Comment: you need to use `eval("function(){}")`, not `Function()` to harness local scope...

Answer (score 2):

To bind a function to a context you have to use bind(object).

```
 var realGlobal = window;// the creator source of the iframe

 var iFrameGlobal = myIFrameGlobal;


(function( ns ) {


  // is the iframe's global, correct!
  var context = this; 

  // button is a custom HTML element in the iFrame, its owner document    
  // is correct. Its basically a custom widget, its JS has been parsed   
  // in that iframe as well.
  var myWidget = button;

  //the content of the new function 
  var script = "var context = window; console.dir(context); return context"; 

  var fn = new Function("{" + script + "}").bind(this);

  var result = fn.apply(myWidget, _args || {});//returns realGlobal      


}( iFrameGlobal ));
```

Comment: Are you sure? the scope will be lost that way because 'this' must be myWidget, thats why I write fn.apply(myWidget, _args || {}); but i never tried n.apply(myWidget, _args || {}).bind(this);

Comment: Hmmm... I am not sure... Damnit!

Comment: anyway, I just tested it, but no. Same result, the context for that new function siwtched back to realGlobal. Thank you, i use bind all the time but never came to the idea to use it here ;-)